# Weblogic DataSource Pool Size

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, datasource, pool

I am triying to determine datasource pool size for Weblogic Server. 
My application should be accept 1000 request per second. Each request just simple database operation like read/write. I set Maximum Capacity as 100 for datasource. How can i measure if this is accepteable? Is there a way? For my traffic test 100 is not enouhg but our db admin says it should be max 150. I would like to hear any ideas about it.

Answer (score 1):

As its not possible to figure out exactly how many of these 1000 requests per sec will actually be doing a DB job and how many would be processing the data you will need to start with 100 connections and increase it if needed.

If the DB task itself is simple (as you state) then you need not configure a very large number of DB connections, but it will be advisable to set the min and max of DB connections in the pool to be same.

Also note the max connection you set in the pool is per managed server, hence if you have more than 1 managed server, then WLS will open no of managed servers x max connections configured in pool to DB.